# Git can't checkout to master

Tags: git, version-control, workflow

So when I try to switch to master I get this:

```
⌘ ~/Documents/foo/foo/ (foo-550) git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    application/models/foo_nrds_model.php
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting


⌘ ~/Documents/foo/foo/ (foo-550) git status
On branch foo-550
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/foo-550'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I also want to mention that I never switched to master yet, only creating branches from the qa branch, what should I do in this case?

Comment: You might be in middle of `rebase`. Can you please try `git rebase --abort` one time?

Comment: Is it possible that foo_nrds_model.php is in the .gitignore file in foo-550, but not in master?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have done some changes in branch and "foo-550" but you have not pushed those changes.

So, when you are trying to change your branch you are getting this error.

If you still have the problem please provide the output of command

> git diff